# Facebook Developer: In-context vs In-line stories

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are developing an app for Facebook and currently struggling to have our use of the "taggable_friends" API approved. This feature of the app review process has been rejected several times, despite many attempts to follow Facebook's guidelines. Basically, we are using the taggable_friends feature to allow users to publish a story to their timeline from our app which tags friends in the post.

Here is the review notice, which has been the same each time the feature was rejected:

> Taggable Friends may only be used to tag friends in in-context stories. It can't be used to for any other purpose, such as competitions, contests or quizzes, or invite friends to use an app. More details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-TAGGABLE_FRIENDS).
>
> Please consider the user_friends permission or App Invites.

That link goes to the app feature review index page for taggable_friends. Here is what that page says about permitted usage of the feature:

> Common Usage
>
> - **yes** Let people tag their friends in in-context stories published by your app. This appends '-with Friend Name' to the end of the user message. E.g. "Having a coffee - with John"
> - **no** Let people mention their friends in-line in stories published by your app. Mentioning is only available in Open Graph stories that use certain additional capabilities. Learn more.
> - **no** Use a person's friends for any purpose other than in-context stories, such as competitions, contests or quizzes, or invite friends to use an app.

My question is about the difference between the first, allowed case and the second, disallowed case. What is the difference between "in-context stories" and "in-line stories"?

To be clear, we are appending the " - with John" tag to the post, but apparently this still does not pass the review.

For some context, our app determines your "Top 5 Friends" according to certain metrics we have developed - this is not the main purpose of the app, but is a feature we want to have approved. The post from the app looks like this (The first occurrence of *UserB* contains the tag):

> UserA is with *UserB*
>
> These are my top friends according to our app!
>
> 1. User1
> 2. User2
> 3. User3
> 4. User4
> 5. User5

("friends" in our app are determined by interactions with posts, not the user's friend list, so there may appear users in this post who cannot be tagged because they are not Facebook friends).

Comment: "Having a coffee - with John" - that's the user who posts this and John being together at Star*ucks/local organic coffee shop. That is the appropriate use case for tagging. Mentioning is "giving a shout" to friends without being at the same location as them - "Miss you, whaddayall doing at the weekend @ berta, @fritzi, @ poopsy?"

Comment: _"this is not the main purpose of the app, but is a feature we want to have approved"_ - pretty sure that won't happen. Apart from it not being an appropriate use case for tagging in the first place, I am also not to sure whether this would even been in line with https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#data, 3.3) "Only use friend data (including friends list) in the person’s experience in your app."

Comment: (And of course everything including and after _"These are my top friends according to our app!"_ in that example post of yours would of course have to be part of the title/description/thumbnail of a link you let the user share - you are not allowed to specify the _message_ part of the post for them, they must have typed that in themselves.)

Comment: Those are all very helpful answers, thank you CBroe. We want to use this app for research purposes, and we had been warned that this is very tricky with Facebook. So would you agree our problems with approval are 1) Mentioning friends in a post (a shout-out as you said) and 2) Specifying the message that is shared to their timeline?

Comment: Yes. Facebook basically wants every user permission your app is asking for to be connected to something that benefits the user's in-app experience. Background analysis for mostly any other purpose you could think of is not allowed. They sell it mostly as a user privacy/data protection feature -
  but let's be honest, it probably rather touches their own business model too closely ... And https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse is quite restrictive about what you can and can't encourage users to do. Check the popups/links behind the (?) buttons, they have examples.